# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream when retrieving Image

Tags: windows-phone-7

I could not figure why only hardcode filename work?

```
1) Without hardcoding filename . Problems:  Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream 

2) But when I hardcode the filename, say, "Test.jpg"  in SaveImageFile()  and GetImageInISO(),
   I can view the image and there is no error message.


 1---------- save an Image from ImageControl :

Private void SaveImageFile()
{

  string strImgFile = strCountry + strCity + ".jpg";

  using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
   {

     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strImgFile, FileMode.Create, store))
       {                         
          WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(g_IntWidth, g_IntHeight);
          wb.Render(cn, new TranslateTransform());
          wb.Invalidate();

      System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, isfs, g_IntWidth, g_IntHeight, 0, 100);

      isfs.Close();                    

         }
    }

}


--2------------Read the image 

 private void GetImageInISO()
 {

     string strPassIn = strCountryName + strCityName + ".jpg";

     BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();


  using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
   {

 using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = store.OpenFile(strPassIn, System.IO.FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))

      {
           if (isfs.Length > 0)                           
             {                           
               bmp.SetSource(isfs);

                isfs.Close();
              }
             else
              {
                MessageBox.Show("Empty file");
               }                        
           }

       }
          image1.Width = bmp.PixelWidth;
           image1.Height = bmp.PixelHeight;
           image1.Source = bmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Such error is usually caused by something else using the file that another piece of code is trying to retrieve. Also, your last 3 lines of code does not cover the case when bmp object is not being set, try wrapping those into if(bmp != null) {     } clause.

Comment: I'm guessing this is b/c of threading, and you're running into this issue b/c your UI is something like a List of countries & cities, and they each have a different image which is retrived simultaneously via this method. Right? you should Lock around your using statement

Comment: @Eugene: I tried all the possible ways. Result is the same. Work on hardcode filename and not the bmp issue.

Comment: It might help if you could post the code that shows how you save/retrieve data at the front end. Also, check to absolutely make sure that the file name that you are asking for really exists in the isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all. Your advice help. the filename contain space characters in which it should not have. after remove the space, it works.